# <input> font line height IE browser compatibility issues

Tags: internet-explorer, input

The following CSS code has a problem in the IE 11 version of the browser,  line height should be 36px, what am I missing?

[This is a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMZF8.png)

It shows normal in chrome.

```css
input {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 background:#fbfbfb;
 color:#666;
 font-size:.875rem;
 line-height:2;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 border:solid .0625rem #ccc;
 padding:.1875rem .5rem;
 margin-bottom:.875rem;
}
```

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First">
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the **height** property for the input text elements.

Code as below:

```
<style>
    input {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        background: #fbfbfb;
        color: #666;
        font-size: .875rem;
        line-height: 2;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: solid .0625rem #ccc;
        padding: .1875rem .5rem;
        margin-bottom: .875rem;
        height:2.2rem;  /*height:36px;*/ /*You could also set the height property to 36px*/    
    }
</style>
```

The result in IE browser (IE 11 version) like this:

[image]